# Questions on SOLID/TDD

Tags: tdd, solid-principles

For a number of years now, I have been interested in TDD, but one or two things just didn't click. I am pretty sure it is the usual thoughts most people have when trying.  "The examples in the book are wonderful, but my code is a lot more complicated than that. I never have a a procedure that does one thing, it will call three others, and they will call three others, and that will get data from the DB... bla bla bla".

A little while ago, I found some videos on SOLID (Anyone who is stuck, thinking TDD would be awesome, but... then find a few videos on SOLID, trust me). Each point became slightly more confusing, until the end, everything just went into place, including how I thought about testing code, and TDD.

I, of course, have a lot of old code, that isn't written like this, but I am okay with that, because I do see a better idea of how it should be. And whenever I work on anything, I can take it out, and do it properly (even when that means cutting out the small part of a method that needs updating, giving it it's own class, and calling that.

It has a few more questions. I would like to know where I might be able to find answers for that, or is there a standard.

**How much should be tested?**
My assumption is all of it. A lot of my functions will be take input parameters, and run a Stored Procedure. My guess on how to test that would be, with a given set of input parameters, is the stored procedure being called the correct one, are the parameters getting put in correct. Often this will be obvious (sometimes there will be array of numbers input that will be transformed to a comma separated string). If nothing else, this example, while the test might not be as valuable, will be documentation.

**How do I name things?**
This is the old problem with development. Should the class be named like the method would be, `UpdateEmployee`, or should there be a whole lot of *`er`* classes (`EmployeeUpdater`, `EmplyeeGetter`, etc.)

**How is IOC generally handled?**
This is still fine for now, I am creating interfaces, implementations, setting up IOC, etc.
I can see though, that pretty soon I am going to have pages and pages and pages of Interface/Class mappings in my IOC initialization method, or I would imagine it splitting into section, with one method that calls a few other methods, each registering classes (by namespace, or something). Is this how it generally works, or are there *smarter* ways of managing this?

Comment: These deserve 3 separate questions here on SO, but even in that case, each question is by itself too broad to be a good fit for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend reading Clean Code by Robert C Martin

In my view...

**How much should be tested?**

There is a big difference between how much and how well.

Ultimately its a judgment call and or a simple cost/benefit analysis.
Critical apps/code should be tested more thoroughly.
Working pure TDD means your code will be highly tested - easily > 90% coverage, but remember there is a difference between test quality and coverage. You may decide to test more edge cases.

You can get 100% coverage with one test case, but its pragmatic to test a range of values e.g. 0, 1, many & boundaries.

**How do I name things?**

For Java as an example, Look at the standard Java API documentation and see how they do it.
Referring to Clean Code, naming is and should be difficult, and maybe refactor if the name no longer fits.

Example Classes from Java's API's

1. FileFilter
2. DesktopManager

Names should make it obvious what the class/method/variable does.

Refer to Kent Beck's Four Rules of Simple Design (Express intent)

**How is IOC generally handled?**

Maybe someone else can expand on this point more, but referring to Extreme  Programming, don't use interfaces for the sake of it, but when you need them. If you only have one concrete instance, you probably don't need an interface. Refactor to add interfaces to follow known design patterns when you have a real need for them.

https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/designDead.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers.
I know it wasn't a very good question.